# Is it possible to click anyway when getting a click exceptions in the selenium Chrome driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, tfsbuild, selenium-chromedriver

We've been build a site for quite a while and I am implementing UI UnitTesting.

It relies heavily on overlaying buttons with "proxies" to allow for more capabilities like dragging from one iframe into another. From a testing perspective, I want/need to "click" the button. It should click the proxy element overlaid on it. Then the test can continue. This works in IE and even Chrome, but when we went to test on the Build Server it failed with the error

> threw exception: System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error:
>   Element is not clickable at point (265, 87). Other element would
>   receive the click: div class="v-iframe-proxy" style="width: 100%;
>   height: 100%;" /div

I am hoping there is a way to ignore this condition and click anyway. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you have 3 options here:
1. Perform click using JavaScript like this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webdriver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", elementToClick);
```

2. Try to click using `new Actions(webdriver).click().build().perform();`
3. Surround your click with try catch and continue execution.

Comment: I'm sure the javascript would work, and would probably work in all the browsers. 2 might be a good solution too, i'll try it now. I wonder about 3... would it click or just move on. It's a lot of changes, but maybe I can do a find/replace...if it works  :)

Comment: Btw, are you capturing screenshots on failure? You're sure that it's actually not overlapped with smthn?
Oh, yeah, it'll throw exception on TRYING to click, not afterwards, however, another option to look at is custom WebDriver events listener, if problem you're describing appears only in certain situations and is actually **NOT** a sign of an issue consider handling WD exception by implementing 'WebDriverEventListener' and running 'eventfiringwebdriver'

Answer (score 0):

I think that your UI tests work on headless browser in the server side. So you need to set width and height initially.

If you print size of the window, you'll see: 0,0

```
System.out.println(driver.manage().window().getSize());
```

So you can set window's size as 1024x600 (or whatever you want):

```
Dimension d = new Dimension(1024,600);
driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
```

Comment: Currently I'm setting the window size as follows : Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

Comment: What is your driver, is it phantomjs? Has the page any ajax request for loading something?